# I Get This Warning Every Time I Run The Code For My Pie Chart In R

Tags: r, plotly, pie-chart

I've successfully gotten my pie chart in r, but i always get this warning when i run the code.

Here is my code below:

```
        plot_ly(data = perc_average_activity_sleep,values = ~ count,
        labels = ~ activity_level, textposition = "inside",textinfo ='label+percent',
        hoverinfo ='value', textfont = list(color ='black'),
        marker = list(colors= c("blue","green", "grey","orange")),
        line=list(color = "white", width = 2),type = "pie")%>%
        layout(title = "Percentage Activity Levels", 
                showlegend = TRUE)
```

This is the warning i get:

Warning: 'pie' objects don't have these attributes: 'line'
Valid attributes include:
'_deprecated', 'automargin', 'customdata', 'customdatasrc', 'direction', 'dlabel', 'domain', 'hole', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverinfosrc', 'hoverlabel', 'hovertemplate', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'hovertext', 'hovertextsrc', 'ids', 'idssrc', 'insidetextfont', 'insidetextorientation', 'label0', 'labels', 'labelssrc', 'legendgroup', 'legendgrouptitle', 'legendrank', 'marker', 'meta', 'metasrc', 'name', 'opacity', 'outsidetextfont', 'pull', 'pullsrc', 'rotation', 'scalegroup', 'showlegend', 'sort', 'stream', 'text', 'textfont', 'textinfo', 'textposition', 'textpositionsrc', 'textsrc', 'texttemplate', 'texttemplatesrc', 'title', 'transforms', 'type', 'uid', 'uirevision', 'values', 'valuessrc', 'visible', 'key', 'set', 'frame', 'transforms', '_isNestedKey', '_isSimpleKey', '_isGraticule', '_bbox'
Warning: 'pie' objects don't have these attributes: 'line'
Valid attributes include:
'_deprecated', 'automargin', 'customdata', 'customdatasrc', 'direction', 'dlabel', 'domain', 'hole', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverinfosrc', 'hoverlabel', 'hovertemplate', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'hovertext', 'hovertextsrc', 'ids', 'idssrc', 'insidetextfont', 'insidetextorientation', 'label0', 'labels', 'labelssrc', 'legendgroup', 'legendgrouptitle', 'legendrank', 'marker', 'meta', 'metasrc', 'name', 'opacity', 'outsidetextfont', 'pull', 'pullsrc', 'rotation', 'scalegroup', 'showlegend', 'sort', 'stream', 'text', 'textfont', 'textinfo', 'textposition', 'textpositionsrc', 'textsrc', 'texttemplate', 'texttemplatesrc', 'title', 'transforms', 'type', 'uid', 'uirevision', 'values', 'valuessrc', 'visible', 'key', 'set', 'frame', 'transforms', '_isNestedKey', '_isSimpleKey', '_isGraticule', '_bbox'
R Console
HTML Widget
plotly
htmlwidget

A pie chart without the warnings

Comment: You can ignore this warning! To turn off use: `options(warn = -1)`.

Comment: You are specifying `line=list(color = "white", width = 2)`, but as the warning says, "'pie' objects don't have these attributes: 'line'".  Leave out the `line = ...` argument.

Comment: @TarJae:  that's terrible advice.  Warnings are helpful.

Comment: @user2554330, I'm not certain if 'terrible' is the appropriate term in this context. However, to better assess the situation, please tell me the consequences of this warning. If there are no consequences, then review all open warnings related to the use of plotly. If these warnings have no significant impact, you can either ignore them or disable them. That's just how it goes sometimes, and it's nothing terrible!

Comment: Your advice wouldn't just disable this warning, it would disable all warnings.  That's why I said it was terrible advice.

Comment: To reiterate, the warning literally say "Warning: 'pie' objects don't have these attributes: 'line' "    

and so take that out.  If you are comfortable with a warning and understand it, you can suppress it for your production version, but it's a bad idea unless you understand what it means.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, and girls but i tried taking out (line=list(color = "white", width = 2) but i got the following error message:  Error: Incomplete expression:    plot_ly(data = perc_average_activity_sleep,values = ~ count,
        labels = ~ activity_level, textposition = "inside",textinfo ='label+percent',
        hoverinfo ='value', textfont = list(color ='black'),
        marker = list(colors= c("blue","green", "grey","orange"))%>%
        layout(title = "Percentage Activity Levels", 
                showlegend = TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in the comments you get this warning because a pie chart in plotly has no line attribute. However, the `marker` attribute has a `line` property. Assuming that you want a white outline for the slices of your pie move the specs for the line inside the list of marker properties:

Using a (minimal) reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(plotly)

perc_average_activity_sleep <- mtcars |>
  dplyr::count(cyl) |>
  dplyr::rename(
    activity_level = cyl,
    count = n
  )

plot_ly(
  data = perc_average_activity_sleep, values = ~count,
  labels = ~activity_level, textposition = "inside", textinfo = "label+percent",
  hoverinfo = "value", textfont = list(color = "black"),
  marker = list(
    colors = c("blue", "green", "grey", "orange"),
    line = list(color = "white", width = 2)
  ),
  type = "pie"
) %>%
  layout(
    title = "Percentage Activity Levels",
    showlegend = TRUE
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you input, but i tried omitting the line, and i ended up with the error message below :               Error: Incomplete expression:         plot_ly(data = perc_average_activity_sleep,values = ~ count,
        labels = ~ activity_level, textposition = "inside",textinfo ='label+percent',
        hoverinfo ='value', textfont = list(color ='black'),
        marker = list(colors= c("blue","green", "grey","orange"))%>%
        layout(title = "Percentage Activity Levels", 
                showlegend = TRUE)

Comment: There is a missing `)` in your code. Try `..., marker = list(colors= c("blue","green", "grey","orange"))*)* %>% ...` where * indicates the missing )

Comment: I'll try that, thanks.